# rows to columns display in mysql just normal simple table

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I display mysql table row as column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366023/how-do-i-display-mysql-table-row-as-column)

I have a column days in which there are two rows day1 and day2, now I need to display days rows as two separate columns.

table name : test

```
column
 **days**
   day1
   day2
```

AFTER RUNNING THE QUERY IT SHOULD BE LIKE :

```
coum1      couml2
day1        day2
```

Need help with doing it in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

I'm note sure if I exactly get what you want' but I think the result should be something like:

```
SELECT days.days as coum1,  days2.days as coum2 from days join days as days2 WHERE days.days = 'day1' AND days2.days = 'day2';
```